# Meaning of 3 hyphens when converting reST files to Markdown?

Tags: markdown, restructuredtext

I'm trying to convert RST files to Markdown files.
In a few scenarios I have something like this in several RST files:

```
---
Copyright to XYZ
This applies in this area.
and so on
---
```

What does the information within the dashed `---` block of text in a RST file represent? I've not found any relevant information in cheat sheets and documentations.

Answer (score 0):

after a quick google, lines with blocks of dashes seem to signify a subtitle according to this:

https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/rst/

Comment: In reST there are no "subtitles". What is defined by an underline is a **section** within a **section structure** similar to what is called headings in HTML.  (The words "title" and "subtitle" being used is just for purpose of example). See the [official documentation](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#section-structure).

Answer (score 0):

In **reStructuredText** the 3 hyphens (or dashes) mean nothing. There are two similar uses:

1. It could be used to [define a section](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections) in which case the hyphens would have to underline some text and have at least the same length.
2. If it were 4 hyphens it would [signify a transition](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#transitions), however that is not the case because syntax rules are strict about the number of hyphens which in your case is only 3 and thus insufficient.

In **Markdown** the [3 hyphens define a Horizontal Rule](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#hr) that will equate to its HTML equivalent [`<hr>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp).

> Horizontal Rules
>
> You can produce a horizontal rule tag (`<hr />`) by placing three or more hyphens, asterisks, or underscores on a line by themselves.

Since the 3 hyphens are meaningless in reST they would be rendered exactly as they are shown. To convert 3 hyphens from reST to Markdown you will have to [escape the characters](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) because otherwise they will be converted to an horizontal rule.

The conversion would consist in escaping the hyphens, by changing this:

```
---
Copyright to XYZ
This applies in this area.
and so on
---
```

to this:

```
\-\-\-
Copyright to XYZ
This applies in this area.
and so on
\-\-\-
```